# Tags with icons that are not sponsored tags

Tags: support, bug, tags, sponsored-tags

I recently saw the [monitoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/monitoring) tag. I noticed it had an image, and since I had seen [this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30187/what-do-icons-on-the-tags-mean), I thought it was a sponsored tag. I had no idea who it could be sponsored by, so I clicked on the tag. The description read:

> Monitoring is the act of looking on the processes or systems for performance, supervision and surveillance.

The description is generic and the tag doesn't seem to be sponsored. I even right-clicked on the icon and searched Google for the image, but could not see any results that suggested sponsorship. If the tag isn't sponsored, why does it have an icon next to it?

Comment: [Related question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/400338/the-monitoring-tag-shouldnt-have-a-sponsored-icon-next-to-it-as-its-name-isn). Even if the tag is sponsored, it shouldn't have the icon because that's only allowed if the sponsor owns trademark on the tag name.

Comment: @AdrianMole Please read the tag wiki excerpt for the [[meta-tag:bug-reports]] tag.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [monitoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/monitoring) tag is sponsored by "Rollbar" - as you can see from [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/monitoring). Presumably, that company provides various monitoring tools/solutions and chose to sponsor the tag in order to get links to their websites in the search output.

It seems that the sponsorship info is not always visible on the linked page! Here's a screenshot of what I see (sometimes needs a browser "Refresh" though):

[image]

Comment: I don't see *anything* on the linked page suggesting that the tag is sponsored by Rollbar, nor do I see any such suggestion on [the detailed tag wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/monitoring/info). The only thing I see indicating a sponsored tag is the icon itself.

Comment: @CodyGray Weird. Sometimes I see the sponsorship info on that link, sometimes I don't. When I refresh the page, the sponsorship info will usually appear.

Comment: Could ad-blockers be at work here?

Comment: In a private window (i.e., logged out) with all scripts and my ad blocker disabled, I don't see that either.

Comment: @RyanM Strange! Looks like Rollbar will be asking S.E. Inc. for a refund, maybe? :-)

Comment: Perhaps some monitoring would be in order here...

Comment: @AdrianMole I reloaded the page like a thousand times, but I don't see anything. I turned on my adblocker and then it showed up :p. So I highly doubt adblockers have anything to do with it.

Comment: I'm not using any ad blockers, so that's unlikely to be the cause. I even disabled userscripts before commenting.

Comment: FWIW I tried reloading a few times and also noticed that sometimes the sponsorship info doesn't load. I opened up chrome dev tools and noticed it's an iframe and any time the iframe didn't load, a request to `https://clc.stackoverflow.com/timeout.gif?ab=0` was initiated. So perhaps it has to do with how fast the page renders on each user's browser.

Comment: For me it was the advanced tracking protection by Firefox that blocked the info. Turning the protection on and off reliably hid or showed the info, resp.

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: I didn't see the ad despite multiple refreshes and changing layout using cmd+-. But then I turned adblock off, and there it is.  Seems multiple competing reasons for why it might not show.

Comment: Hmm ... just checked with my sockpuppet (101 rep) and it doesn't see the links either. I can only see them when logged out.

Comment: Now I want to not be able to see the sponsored links! A  batch has just appeared for the C++ tag (but no icon on the tag itself). Grrr...

Answer (score 8):

As @AdrianMole mentioned, It's a sponsered tag. But the info is not visible for small screens.

My screen size is small and I can't see the info. But when I press `control` + `-` multiple times (to make it big enough), and then `refresh`, then I can see the info.

As @DanielWiddis mentioned in comments, adblock may be another reason if you can't see it, because it's an iframe ad and adblock blocks it.

Comment: I view the page on my UHD monitor and I don't see the info... I suppose I could try buying an "8k" monitor, but that's getting a little silly ;-).

Comment: I don't think monitor size is the issue. I have a fairly large monitor and I don't see anything.

Comment: @Polygnome updated the answer. maybe it's because of adblock.

Comment: I have a fairly large monitor and no ad blocking, yet I don't see the sponsorship information, so clearly both of these theories are incorrect or incomplete.

Comment: For me, the screen size seems to actually be the issue. I was trying on a private session with no extensions anyway but I couldn't see it. Zooming out to 90% then refreshing made that "banner" appear. However, when I went back to my regular browser (with ad-block) I couldn't get it to appear. Turning off ad-block made it appear again (with 90% zoom).  So, I'm quite certain that those two elements play a factor, if not solve the problem completely.

Comment: @CodyGray Other theories: (1) Info is hidden from users with two names, if the initial letters of those names are separated by 4 (CG) or 5 (HM) alphabet points; (2) It's a **bug**!

Comment: @CodyGray - could it be you've gotten the reduce ads privilege (https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads) switched on? I think this might be the cause of you not seeing it.  

Disclaimer: I'm an employee of Stack, working as a Product Manager in the Advertising team

Comment: @JD-Stack i also noticed that often it takes some seconds to load (around 3 sec), and someone in comments said that he's getting timeout. so i think it may be due to slow connection as well.