# The [monitoring] tag shouldn't have a sponsored icon next to it, as its name isn't copyrighted by the sponsor

Tags: bug, tags, sponsored-tags

Inspired by [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/400317/tags-with-icons-that-are-not-sponsored-tags).

The [monitoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/monitoring) tag currently has a sponsored icon next to it. But we've been told that:

> we only allow [setting the icon] for advertisers that own a copyright on the name of the tag
>
> [— Will Westendorf](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/387263/2752075)

I think it's safe to assume that a generic word like "monitoring" can't be copyrighted.

If this policy is still in effect, I suggest that the icon should be removed.

---

We've been there before. [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c)/[c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) tags [used to have `Qt` icon on them](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/393124/2752075) for a short moment, until it was reported on Meta.

Comment: A related issue: that answer almost certainly should have said "copyright", not "trademark."  Names are trademarked.  Creative works are copyrighted.

Comment: @RyanM Thank you. "Copyright" sounded off to me, but I wasn't sure.

Comment: Related post: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/400317/12708583

Comment: Looks like Rollbar have others they probably shouldn't too, e.g. [tag:qa], while weirdly *not* sponsoring, err, [tag:rollbar].

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I'm in the process of removing it, should be gone by EOD today, but to be safe I'd check again tomorrow to be sure :).

Disclaimer: I'm an employee of Stack, working as a Product Manager in the Advertising team